# Wordpress to Drupal 6 Feed

Tags: wordpress, drupal, feed

I have a drupal website and i am using wordpress for blog.My goal is to catch all the posts of wordpress blog to my drupal website using feed burner.I am using feeds module (drupal) but the problem is that "image tag" is not displaying in drupal site although all other contents of wordpress are showing.

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably more of the input filters set on the Drupal side than an issue with the feed.

Check the allowed tags on the Drupal side and make sure  tag is allowed.

Comment: Thanks Bright Plum. :) I am missing the <img> tag in input filters.I added in input filter and its working.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 things you can do here:
There is a core module called aggregator, that should do the trick.

For images, either you have to show the path same as it is wordpress, or custom code it to save it locally and then show it.

By the way, are you saving the posts to Drupal too?